# How to get image width and height from a network url

Tags: android, imageview

I am working on an android app and using REST APIs in it. I am receiving image urls from server and I want to show these images according to the original height of the image using image url.

How can I get the width and height of image using network image url. I have already tried getting bitmap from the string url but for this I want to perform this in background thread which leads the image loading very slow.

Is there any way I can get the image width and height from image url and can show the image in imageview according to the width and height.

Please help me if anyone know about this.

Thanks a lot in advanced.

Comment: Unless you have those parameters in the URL, I don't think that you can get the properties of image just from it's URL.

Comment: try this sample code... https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Answer (score 7):

```
URL url = new URL("url/image.jpg");
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
```

for width:

```
bmp.getWidth();
```

for height:

```
bmp.getHeight();
```

for setting in imageview:

```
ImageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Further Reference:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#getHeight%28%29

Comment: I have a network url of image from server. How can I get width and height from that url

Comment: In what technology your api developed?
you can simply send particular height and width from url instead of sending image. OR simply create another api function that send just width and height of that image.

Comment: You are a legend. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
/* your library */
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'    
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'

/* your code */

    Glide.with(this)
            .asBitmap()      //get hieght and width 
            .load("link image")
            .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                @Override
                public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, @Nullable 
                    Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
                    Log.d("TAG", "onResourceReady: "+resource.getWidth()+"    
                    "+resource.getHeight());
                }
            });

    //////////////////////////////////////

    Glide.with(this)
            .asFile()     // get size Image 
            .load("link image")
            .into(new SimpleTarget<File>() {
                @Override
                public void onResourceReady(@NonNull File resource, @Nullable 
                    Transition<? super File> transition) {
                    fab_full.setLabelText(""+resource.length());
                }
            });
```